How to disable TestNG console logging [main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils -
I have an automation framework using Selenium, TestNG, and Log4j for logging. When running the tests, TestNG generates a specific log to the console that I'd like to suppress. The log message is:
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 1 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 4 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.


I've included my pom.xml file for reference:
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aeonbits.owner</groupId>
            <artifactId>owner</artifactId>
            <version>${owner.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4jcore.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

And here is my log4j configuration:
status=warn
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=LogToConsole
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
#appender.file.type = File
#appender.file.name = LogToFile
#appender.file.fileName=logs/app.log
#appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
#appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
# Rotate log file
appender.rolling.type=RollingFile
appender.rolling.name=LogToRollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName=log4j2/log4j2-automation-test.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=log4j2/$${date:yyyy-MM}/log4j2-automation-test-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=50MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max=10
# Log to console and rolling file
logger.app.name=com.da.mobile.automation
logger.app.level=debug
logger.app.additivity=false
logger.app.appenderRef.rolling.ref=LogToRollingFile
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref=LogToConsole
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=LogToConsole

Could you please suggest ways to configure TestNG or Log4j to prevent this particular log message from being displayed in the console?

Have you tried adding log4j.logger.org.testng=WARN into your log4j.properties and see if that helps ?

You use slf4j-simple as SLF4J implementation, which means that software coded against the SLF4J API will not use Log4j Core as logging backend.
You should replace it with another SLF4J implementation:

either the log4j-slf4j2-impl bridge from SLF4J 2 to Log4j API,
or the log4j-slf4j-impl bridge from SLF4J 1 to Log4j API.

